# null reference error instead of validation error in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I recently discovered this error in my app and I wondered if has always been there or if it is a part of an upgrade from rails 3 to 4. (or just me)

In my new action on my controller I load a list of values (`@workers`) which is needed in my form view.

```
 def new
    @hour = Hour.new
    @hour.job_id = params[:job_id]    

    @workers = Worker.inactive(false).order(:name)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hour }
    end
  end
```

I have a required field on my Hour model and if I leave if empty I would expect a validation error. But instead get a null reference on `@workers.collect`..

If I ad the `@workers` to my create action it triggers the validation warning.

But I just find it weird that I need to define the `@workers` in the create action

Is that expected behavior or did I screw up something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `create` action tries to render `new` template if validation fails. But the `new` template, as you wrote, relies on `@workers` variable, which is `nil` in this case, because you don't set it in `create`. Nothing unexpected here. You do need to set this variable in (or before) `create` too, for example like this:

```
before_action :set_workers, only: %i[new create]

# ...
private

def set_workers
  @workers = Worker.inactive(false).order(:name)
end
```

This behavior hasn't changed since Rails 2, at least.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense, just never ran into it before or long time ago. Expecting too much magic from Rails :)